# Interpolation of varieble inside substitution

Tags: bash, expression, substitution

I am learning bash scripting. In the context of this piece of code:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
DATARECORD="last=Clifford,first=Johnny Boy,state=CA"
COMMA1=`expr index "$DATARECORD" ','`  # 14 position of first comma
```

When do `` `expr index $CHOP1FIELD ','` ``  it does not work whereas i do`` `expr index "$CHOP1FIELD" ','` `` it starts to work.
Can I ask for an explanation what is the reason I need those double quotes?

Answer (score 2):

> Can I ask for an explanation what is the reason I need those double quotes?

Expressions not inside double quotes undergo *word splitting* expansion. Because of that, the result of expansion is split on spaces, so it becomes:

```
expr index last=Clifford,first=Johnny Boy,state=CA ','
```

and executes `expr` with 4 arguments, one too much. The call is invalid, and `expr` should exit with an error.

Do not use backticks `. Check your scripts with shellcheck.